# Help with Rebus or Wuzzle KCIK

Tags: word, wordplay, rebus

rebus puzzle:  KCIK?  In the middle of the block, all in caps and all in bold.

Anyone have a clue?

CI in K's?  2Ks around See?

See eye in 2kays?  Anyone?

Answer (score 11):

It's

> KICKBACK.

(Answers need to be at least 30 characters, which is the only reason for this paragraph.)

Comment: I agree, but back could also be flip.

Comment: I don't think that makes an actual word.

Comment: It [does](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kickflip).

Comment: Kickflip? Flipkick? I'm not seeing it: what am I missing?

Comment: Kick flip is two separate words, as defined by the dictionary, if we go that way. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kick-flip (note the hyphen, representing a space).

Comment: "also written [kickflip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickflip);" but it wouldn't make it any less valid as a solution either way.

Comment: Oh, apparently it's a skateboarding thing. I had no idea. (And Will, I completely missed the link in your comment -- sorry about that.)

Comment: @Inazuma + how are we differentiating between equally valid the answer spoilered above with (idiomatic = "relax") or without (word = "recoil") a space anyway? Should we, even?

Comment: I think any answer that works is an acceptable answer. So any of the options we've been discussing here should be OK for the original rebus.

Comment: Thank you ALL so much!!!  Kickback is what I decided to go with.  Wish me luck.  You guys are great!!!!

Comment: If you like my answer you might want to accept it by clicking the checkmark thing to its left. (Or, since apparently this is a puzzle someone else has given you, you might want to wait and see whether that answer is acceptable to them.)